# How to query Security Policy with AdsiSearcher in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, system-administration, penetration-testing

I am trying to find all servers that set `TrustedForDelegation : True`, I am able to find all servers using `([adsisearcher]"ObjectCategory=Computer").Findall().properties` but I can't see any of the security policy properties. How would I go about viewing filtering for security policy properties?

Btw the reason I am using `AdsiSearcher` is because I don't have the Active Directory module available to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trusted for Delegation permission is stored in the `userAccountControl` attribute in AD, which is a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), meaning that the value indicates several flags that can be on or off. The full list is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties).

Adding this to your query is a little tricky. It requires a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) comparison to see if a specific flag is turned on. AD allows this through a [matching rule OID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/4e638665-f466-4597-93c4-12f2ebfabab5) called `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND`.

You would use it in an LDAP query like this:

```
(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=524288)
```

So your code to find all computers with the Trusted for Delegation permissions would look something like this:

```
([adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=524288))").Findall()
```